# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Carousel.stopSlideShow

Tags: javascript, error-handling, carousel

getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Carousel.stopSlideShow but not sure how to fix it!

I am hoping to create a smart carousel class that can allow me to create multiply carousels. I tried everything that I could think so but can't figure out how to fix the problem.

Also having these problems:

1. with the restartSlideShow, after is goes through the three slides I have it goes blank instead of restarting.
2. when I click on the control-dots or the control-left and right elements it goes blank as well.

Any thoughts?
Thank you.

```
const trueNumber = function (num, max) {
    return num < 0 ? num + max : num;
}
const signNumber = function (num, max) {
    return num > max * 0.5 ? num % max - max : num;
}
const wrapNumber = function (num, max) {
    return trueNumber(signNumber(num, max), max);
}

class Carousel {
    constructor(o) {
        Object.assign(this, o); //this allow us to mke a copy of the carousel

        let carousel = this;

        this.currentSlide = 0; //the current slide is always going to be zero

        this.slides = this.element.find(".slide"); //getting the slides from html
        this.dots = this.element.find(".control-dot"); //getting the dots of the pagination from html

        if (this.timing) { //is this.timing exist or a timer have started then start the slideshow
            this.startSlideShow();
        }

        this.element.find(".control-left").on("click", function () {
            carousel.changeSlide(false);
            carousel.restartSlideShow();//this is saying if the user didnt touch anything then restart the slideshow
        });

        this.element.find(".control-right").on("click", function () {
            carousel.changeSlide(true);
            carousel.restartSlideShow();
        });

        this.element.find(".control-dot").on("click", function () {
            let index = $(this).index(); //jquery that allow us to find the index of the clicked dot
            carousel.changeSlide(index);
            carousel.restartSlideShow();
        });
    }

    changeSlide(direction) {
        this.previousSlide = this.currentSlide;
        if (direction == true) {
            this.currentSlide++;
        } else if (direction == false) {
            this.currentSlide--;
        } else {
            if (this.currentSlide == direction) {
                return;
            }
            this.currentSlide = direction;
            direction = this.currentSlide > this.previousSlide;
        }
        this.currentSlide = wrapNumber(this.currentSlide, this.slides.lenght); /*this is going to help us restart the slide and go back to index 0*/
        this.showSlide(direction); //will show the slide
    }
    showSlide(direction) {
        let c = this;
        this.slides.removeClass("moving left right center"); //remove any class from the slide
        this.slides.eq(this.previousSlide).addClass("center"); //from the slides if the current slide is the previous slide give it the class of center
        if (direction) { //this let us check the direction
            this.slides.eq(this.currentSlide).addClass("right");//if direction is true move right
        } else {
            this.slides.eq(this.currentSlide).addClass("left");//if direction is false move left
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            c.dots.eq(c.currentSlide).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active"); //when we click on one of the dots is active and it becomes bigger by adding
            //the class active
            c.slide.eq(c.currentSlide).removeClass("left right").addClass("center moving");
            if (direction) {
                c.slides.eq(c.previousSlide).removeClass("center").addClass("left moving");
            } else {
                c.slides.eq(c.previousSlide).removeClass("center").addClass("right moving");
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    startSlideShow() {
        let c = this; //c stands for carousel
        c.stopSlideShow();
        c.timer = setTimeout(function () { //everytime certain amount of time happens this is what is going to happen
            c.changeSlide(true);
            c.showSlide(true);
            c.startSlideShow();
        }, c.timing);
    }
    stopSlideShow() {
        let c = this;

        c.stopSlideShow();

        c.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            c.changeSlide(true);
            c.showSlide(true);
            c.startSlideShow();
        }, c.timing);
    }
    restartSlideShow() {
        let c = this;
        this.stopSlideShow();
        if (this.timing) {
            this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                c.startSlideShow();
            }, 5000);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `stopSlideShow()` is recursive with no exit - it's blowing the stack.  It also looks like it's doing the wrong thing, should be more like: `stopSlideShow() { let c = this; clearTimeout(c.timer); }`

Comment: that semi works but then I am also having issues with the control left, right and dots, when I try clicking the slider goes white. Do you see anything out of the ordinary in the rest of the code? wondering if the problem is my css. Thank you!

Comment: That's another question entirely.